# Removing Axis Hashmarks from Graph

Tags: graphics

I have the following graph but I am trying to remove the x-axis and y-axis dash marks. How do I do it? Any way to put the $y$ axis label on top of the line rather than to the right?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=center,
        xmax = 1.1,
        ymax = 1.1,
        ylabel=$y$,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ]
        \addplot [domain=0:1,samples=250, ultra thick, blue] {sqrt(x)}
            node [pos=0.9, above left] {$y=\sqrt{x}$};
        \addplot [domain=0:1,samples=250, ultra thick, red ] {x}
            node [pos=0.3, below right] {$y=x$};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So you mean no ticks for both axis and change the label position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1** *I am trying to remove the x-axis and y-axis dash marks.*

You can remove the ticks and tick labels globaly using `\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}` or in the `axis` environment using `xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,xticklabels=\empty,yticklabels=\empty`

**Q2** *Any way to put the $y$ axis label on top of the line rather than to the right?*

Here, you can define the node where to place the axis label using `x label style={at={(axis description cs:1,0)},anchor=west}, y label style={at={(axis description cs:0,1)},anchor=south},`

[image]

```
\documentclass[varwidth=\maxdimen]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, ticks=none}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \caption{this is caption}
        \label{fig:fig}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                axis lines=center,
                xmax = 1.1,
                ymax = 1.1,
                x label style={at={(axis description cs:1,0)},anchor=west},
                y label style={at={(axis description cs:0,1)},anchor=south},
                ylabel=$y$,
                xlabel=$x$,
                xtick=\empty,
                ytick=\empty,
                xticklabels=\empty,
                yticklabels=\empty
                ]
                \addplot [domain=0:1,samples=250, ultra thick, blue] {sqrt(x)}
                node [pos=0.9, above left] {$y=\sqrt{x}$};
                \addplot [domain=0:1,samples=250, ultra thick, red ] {x}
                node [pos=0.3, below right] {$y=x$};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Any way to add a caption on top of the graph? I used \caption{This is a caption} but its not working.

Comment: when you put it in a `figure` environment, it will work. BTW. @Zarko was a little bit faster than me, maybe you can give him aloso some credit ;)

Comment: @Jess I edited the answer, now with caption

Comment: Excelsior your awesome!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Do you after something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    ticks= none,  % <--- added
    xmax = 1.1, xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={right}, % <--- added position of xlabel 
    ymax = 1.1, ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={above}, % <--- added position of ylabel 
    domain=0:1, samples=250, % <--- both graph has the same domain and number of samples
    ]
\addplot [ultra thick, blue] {sqrt(x)}
    node [pos=0.9, above left] {$y=\sqrt{x}$};
\addplot [ultra thick, red ] {x}
    node [pos=0.3, below right] {$y=x$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe the OP meant just without the tick marks, but with the tick numbers? Like `ytick style = {draw=none}, xtick style = {draw=none}`?

Comment: @Marijn, you may be right. I thing about this, however, numbers without tick are so strange to me :-).